# Creating Xcode iPhone Library

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have looked through a lot of information about this, but I haven't quite found the right approach to what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm not sure if **creating an Xcode library** is what I'm trying to accomplish, but this is the idea: **I want to create something that will be loaded from individual Xcode projects by adding a line that will import it.** The purpose of this is for my Xcode projects to **recognize created macros or other methods** that I use quite a lot. How could I accomplish doing this task? Does anyone have any ideas or advanced tutorials? Thanks in advance!

How can I create a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you would like to create static library? Then you could create one aggregate header to include all headers in library. After you create static library it's very easy to include it in the project. Just drag and drop its folder to your project and add `#import` with aggregate header.  [Here's](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/) explained concept of static libraries, and on [this](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/) site you have more information how to build one in Xcode 4.